# Using Drupal, how do I force t('') to populate the string?

Tags: php, drupal, internationalization

I am trying to make sure that all of the translatable strings are present in the database. Some of them appear very rarely (various form validation errors), therefore it would be a pain to reproduce them all.

Instead, I've created an admin module that, once called, goes through an array of all translatable strings and executes `echo t('[the string from the array]')`.

After this, I expect to be able to translate those strings using `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`. But not all of them are there.

- What am I missing?
- If that's for some reason not possible, is there any function that would force entry?

Comment: Can you show an example of your code?

Comment: It is as simple as `<?php /* [..] */ foreach(array('foo', 'bar') as $t) echo t($t);?>`. The text is printed as expected. However, it is no saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and use "Translation template extractor" module as suggested by Vlad Stratulat.
The module let you parse all of your modules and themes and extract all the strings that are used in t() function.

The result is a .po file with all the original/translation string pairs.
You can open the .po (it's a plain text file, so use your favorite text-editor or POEdit software) and check and translate the missing strings.
Finally re-upload the complete .po in Drupal.

Comment: Can I simply create the `.po` file myself? I have all the strings in an array. Where can I get `.po` file specs?

Comment: Yes, the .po format is simple, you can handly create yours, but for simlicity I suggest you to let the module parse all of them!
You can copy the format from this file: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/6.x/iconizer/iconizer-6.x-1.3.ca.po (my Iconizer module, catalan translation)

Comment: And that Guy didn't wanted to listen to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
foreach(array(t('foo'), t('bar')) as $t) {
    echo $t;
}
```

You should never use `t()` to translate variables, such as calling `t($text)`. Read about [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function.

But anyway, the best way is to create `.po` file from your module and export it to Drupal using [Translation template extractor](http://drupal.org/project/potx).

This module will extract all your translatable strings and will save it into language specific file which you can then use in any other sites where you would like to use your module.

Comment: I would prefer to do it from within the code if that is possible.

Comment: This module definitely will help you a lot.

Comment: Why would `t()` work in `foreach(array(t('foo'), t('bar')) as $t)` context but not when echoed?

Comment: Did you saw my updated answer? I echoed there `$t` variable which is result of `t('string')`.

Comment: What's the purpose of that? I don't care about the output. I only need the strings in the array to be saved in the database.

Comment: I'm trying to help you out here and seems that you don't want to understand. Read about `t()` function on Drupal API. It says that you should never use `t()` to translate variables, such as calling `t($text)` what exactly you are doing in your code!!!

Comment: No, you read the docs again. They are referring to a completely different scenario, e.g. user input. In my case, all translations are coming from an `array`.